# Add callback for when a Toast message closes

Tags: android, toast

I have a Toast message I use as a splash screen which I would like to add a callback to once it closes.  How is this achievable in Android?

```
// Splash
LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.splash, (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.frameLayout1));
layout.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
Toast toast = new Toast(getApplicationContext());
toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0, 0);
toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
toast.setView(layout);
toast.show();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't test this but you might be able to add a visibilitychanged listener to the view that you pass to the toast, refer to  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onWindowVisibilityChanged(int)

Alternatively, you could set a timer using the toast duration fetched by getDuration()

Is there a reason you are using a toast for this? Why not updating the view using setview after a defined period of time or using a seperate Activity?

Comment: @Nissan, thanks for the accept. Could you elaborate on which method worked for you?